# SPFX trigger Power Automate Flow

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, power-automate, spfx

I'm trying to run power automate flow from my spfx. I found tutorial how to do it, but I'm getting error code 401 unauthrized.
I've checked it in Postman and it's working.

I made my flow in Power Automate, trigger is request http, listening to anyone. Postman is workng well.
But in my code in SPFx, I have the same properties like in Postman and it's not working.
I was trying to add some authorization in Azure Portal, but nothing helps.